# Opening templates with Twig without sandbox

Tags: php, twig

I am using a rather light framework to build a CMS. I'm also using `Twig Template Engine` so that I may open up layout customization to customers via a texteditor at the site.

I read about Twig and sandboxing but I'm thinking using it is unnescessary. All and all I'm basically retrieving very minimal information from the database for the site in all cases and all these queries are limited to that specific website ie. you cannot create custom queries or retrieve any data that is not from your website.

There should not be any harmful object data which the customer can use and isn't Twig limiting all PHP functions to a bare minimum? You can't even manipulate objects, rather just create your own variables from object values and manipulate those.

The only thing I am allowing the customer to manipulate is views at front-end.

**However is there anything in Twig that might be potentially dangerous without sandboxing ie. can people who manipulate layout files do damage or cause harm?**

Comment: Twig shouldn't be used to modify objects and/or its attributes. Twig should be used to present data to the user. Fetching data from external sources should be done in your controller or through ajax (with jsonp), I'm not sure why you would want to disable the autoescaping from twig tbh.

Comment: I seriously can't understand what you just read from my text to come up with a comment like that?

Comment: Then I misread the text, what do you mean then?